# How to compare UIButton title with another string in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

```
NSString *s1= [btnStreetType titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];

BOOL str= [s1 isEqualToString:s1 ];
```

In the code above, why does `isEqualToString` return NO? I have to check whether the title is an empty string or not, but it always returns NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess s1 or btnStreetType is nil. Otherwhise, there is no reason that test to return NO. Even on empty strings (@""), it should return YES.

Check `btnStreetType` first, I think the problems comes from it, it may be nil, because `titleForState` has no reason to return a nil value if called on a valid object.

Comment: thanks for reply.it returns nil so the problem was.. thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if([yourstring isEqualToString:button string]){
BOOL str = YES;
}
else{
BOOL str = NO;
}
```

one thing also check that is your strings are nil or not.you see check it by `NSLog`.if not then it should work.i hope this will help you.